# spring boot common controller prefix

Tags: spring-boot

I need to set a prefix for my controllers: `/api`. But this shouldn't impact the actuator endpoints eg `/health`. I know you can set the `server.context-path` but this will also impact the actuator endpoints. I know i can also put an annotation on each controller, but this could easily lead to problems when some other developer forgets it. So is there an easy way to have this prefix on each custom controller but not the spring boot actuator endpoints? Don't really car if it is with java config or some property that i haven't found yet.

Thanks

Comment: Use `server.servlet-path` to set the path.

Comment: `servlet.servlet-path` also moves the spring actuator endpoints behind the prefix. So has the same problem as `server.context-path`